# Connecting a SQL database to asp.net web form

Tags: asp.net, sql, webforms

i've created a database and called it "**database1**", now i went to web.config to set the the connection string, this is what i've added :

```
    <add name="dbconstring"
 connectionString=" Server=(local);Integrated Security=SSPI;Database=Database1;"
 providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

and when i run this code :

```
 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconstring"].ToString());

        con.Open();
        string strqry = "INSERT INTO data (first,second) VALUES (value1,value2)";
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand myCom = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(strqry, con);
        int numrow = myCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
```

note: there's a table called "data" with two columns "first" and "second" in the database.

i get error says "**The system cannot find the file specified**"

and if i try to view the table i get this :

[image]

any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

value1 and value2 are strings in this example so just escape them. Use following code:

```
INSERT INTO data (first,second) VALUES ('value1','value2')
```

Comment: can you post the ddl of the table?

Comment: sorry im new but where i can find that, i've created the table manually from the SQL window in visual studio.

Comment: @j3tb1ack Although he did need to quote those strings, that's still not the problem. Neither is the DDL of the table relevant to this issue. The problem is it's not finding his database file. My guess is that his connection string is incorrect but I am not a SQL Server expert.

Comment: Well if the connection string is the issue then here is an example of sql express connection strings (assuming you are using sql express):  

<add name="dbconstring" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI; AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|somedb.sdf; User Instance=true"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />